# How to get rid of Froala WYSIWYG editor's text-based watermark (Yii2 widget)

Tags: yii2, wysiwyg, froala

I'm using Froalla's WYSIWYG widget for Yii2 for my non-profit project. I acknowledged I lack research and have no prior knowledge that it's a paid service, thus I'm struggling with the multiple "Powered by froalla editor" watermark" in my site. Even after I delete the widget call in my view and delete the published froalla's asset folder, the text-based watermark remain.

What should I do to get rid of the watermark other than using the activation key as I intended not to use it anymore? Thank you.

Comment: So is the watermark on the images uploaded using the editor in question? If so - there is no easy way to remove them without specialized software, better to upload them again with different editor. And if so - it's not the question for this Stack.

Answer (score 1):

attribution: false

you need to set this option as false to remove the watermark.

please see this link
https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options/#attribution

Answer (score 0):

This question has been around a bit but I thought I would add some clarification to what he was asking in case someone else finds this and wonders. I believe what the OP was referring to was the text the unlicensed editor adds to the bottom of the content that the editor saves. It does this because it is a paid product and using the free version is meant to be evaluation only so it "watermarks" your content. It's not some magic watermark, it is just added text to the content. If you pay for it and add the license key, it stops adding the text.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... This is quite old, but this might help.

I only tried it on **CKEDITOR** and it worked fine. You might try it in your case or whichever the case maybe.

First, make sure you get the class name of the watermark element, in CKEDITOR it's `ck-powered-by__label`, you can find this by inspecting on the element.

Then in your local CSS file, style it in a way it won't be able to breath :)

```
.ck-powered-by__label {
    padding: 0px !important;
    width: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    max-width: 0px !important;
    max-height: 0px !important;
    display: none !important;
    position: fixed;
    right: -300px;
    bottom: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide all from froala using CSS:

```
a[id="fr-logo"] {
  display: none !important;
}
p[data-f-id="pbf"] {
  display: none !important;
}
a[href*="www.froala.com"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```